# Postgrey: Put greylisted emails to a directory instead of rejecting them totally

Tags: postfix, postgrey

I'm docker-mailserver to manage my incoming and outgoing emails. One annoying thing is that some of the emails are greylisted (e.g. from amazon or digitalocean). I've already whitelisted these domains, but was thinking if there is an option to put incoming, greylisted emails into a dedicated directory on my inbox.

So instead of rejecting some emails completely it would put them into "postgrey" directory (and responding the sender that the message was rejected, as usually).

I've looked into the documentation but was unable to find such an option.

Comment: Huh? That is not what greylisting does, and your request doesn't make sense in context. Greylisting does not reject mail at all. Greylisting introduces a _short_ delay in delivery, by deferring the message, because legitimate senders will try sending the message again in a few minutes, while many spam bots cannot retry a message. Are you referring to something else?

Comment: @MichaelHampton what will happen to the message if the sender won't try sending the it again after short delay?

Comment: Then it was spam and you didn't want to see it anyway. Legitimate senders always try again.

Comment: @MichaelHampton i would like a mechanism to put the "not yet tried again messages" to a custom directory on my inbox, so in case of expecting an email which was blocked by postgrey I could access it immediately instead of waiting for re-sending

Comment: SMTP doesn't work like that. It either accepts the mail or does not.